# Internet not working on Puppy 6.3 64 bit O.S using Frisbee telephonic pppoe connection

Tags: internet, ppp, puppy-linux

I have Dialup broadband internet connection. On windows I use PPPOE Connection type  with giving connection server name, user name and password, it works perfectly on windows.

---

On Linux Puppy (slacko) 6.3 64 bit version it is detecting eth0 and I am  getting dynamic IP. But looks like it is not connecting using Frisbee telephonic pppoe connection with user name and password. I am only able to connect to ISP internet address but not connecting on other websites.

Do I need some other settings?